# TestNG parallel execution on multiple browsers always considering single browser only

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to execute a test in multiple browsers, in parallel using TestNG.

But it is always considering second mentioned browsers only.

TestNG.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Parallel Tests" verbose="1" thread-count="10" parallel="tests">
    <tests> 
        <test name="Test1">
            <parameters>
                <parameter name="platform" value="Windows" />
                <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
                <parameter name="version" value="8" />
            </parameters>
            <classes>
                <class name="com.tribune.uiautomation.testscripts.TestEngine"/>
            </classes>
        </test> <!-- Test -->

        <test name="Test2">
            <parameters>
                <parameter name="platform" value="Windows" />
                <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
                <parameter name="version" value="8" />
            </parameters>
            <classes>
                <class name="com.tribune.uiautomation.testscripts.TestEngine"/>
            </classes>
        </test> <!-- Test -->

    </tests>    
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

My TestEngine class:

```
@BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void beforeTest(String browser){
        try{    
            Property.BrowserName = browser;
            System.out.println("BrowserName got from XML is "+Property.BrowserName);
}

@test
public void Execute test() {

//code for launching browser & performing tests...
}
```

Console output is similar to:

```
log4j:WARN [] should be System.out or System.err.
log4j:WARN Using previously set target, System.out by default.
[TestNG] Running:
  D:\Selenium_Projects\WorkSpace_Personal\TribuneWebScriptLess\TestNG.xml

BrowserName got from XML is chrome
BrowserName got from XML is firefox

//from here onwards it is considering only firefox browser only (i.e. both the tests mentioned in TestNG.xml are running in firefox only)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i remove  (parallel="tests") attribute in TestNG.xml , Tests are working fine. Problem comes only with Parallel attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the problem, The browserName variable is Static. As static variables are shared across the threads, every time a thread is setting browserName value, it is overwriting the existing value.

So i have fixed the issue by defining the browserName variable as Threadlocal variable. But by the approach of defining lot of variable as ThreadLocal, will it be problem?